# What classes represent the four different scopes: page, request, session, and application?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

What classes represent the four different scopes: page, request, session, and application? I am unsure of the first one, but think the rest might be ServletRequest, HttpSession, and ServeltContext.

Comment: He's asleep atm. And he's too proud to ask people. Silly man.

Comment: In that case, you might think about registering an account on SO...sounds like you'll be asking many more questions on his behalf. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
application = javax.servlet.ServletContext
config = javax.servlet.ServletConfig
exception = java.lang.Throwable
out = javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter
page = java.lang.Object
PageContext = javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext
request = javax.servlet.ServletRequest
response =  javax.servlet.ServletResponse
session =   javax.servlet.http.HttpSession
```

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you:

```
<%= page.getClass() %>
```

:-P

Comment: I don't have too much info on what he's doing. So I am not sure he even has the page object.

Comment: All JSP pages have the `page` object available.